# Force equation numbering to the same line of case equation

Tags: pdftex, line-breaking, labels

It seems that the column is so narrow that it can not bear the whole equation:

```
\begin{equation}
        R(p_i|G) =
        \begin{cases}
            ep_{p_i} + (1- UA(p_i|G))\cdot ({r_G - ep_{p_i}})
            &\text{ if } ep \leq r_G \\
            ep_{p_i} + UA(p_i|G)\cdot ({r_G - ep_{p_i}})
            &\text{ if } ep > r_G 
        \end{cases}
        \label{eq:dis}
    \end{equation}
```

The result is:

[image]

Question: how can I force (7) to the same line with the equation.

Comment: It seems that you haven't room for equation number. To give you some advice, you need to provide minimal working example. Can be equation/number protruded out of text (column) width?

Comment: Which document class, which font size, and which font family do you use?

Comment: I use AAMAS extended abstract class. Font size 9.5pt, arial . http://sis.smu.edu.sg/sites/default/files/sis/conference/aamas2016/paper-submission/aamas2016_example.zip

Answer (score 4):

Something like this?

[image]

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath} % for '\text' macro
\newcommand\mcr[1]{\multicolumn{1}{@{}r@{}}{#1}} % handy shortcut macro

\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
\medmuskip=2mu   % reduce spacing around binary operators
\thickmuskip=3mu % reduce spacing around relational operators
\renewcommand\arraystretch{1.5}
R(p_i\mid G) =
\left\{\begin{array}{@{}l@{}}
   \textit{ep}_{p_i} + (1- \textit{UA}(p_i\mid G)) ({r_G - \textit{ep}_{p_i}})\\
   \mcr{\text{if  $\textit{ep} \leq r_G$}} \\[1ex]
   \textit{ep}_{p_i} + \textit{UA}(p_i\mid G) ({r_G - \textit{ep}_{p_i}}) \\
   \mcr{\text{ if $\textit{ep} > r_G$}}
   \end{array}\right.
        \label{eq:dis}
    \end{equation}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Quite similar but not exactly, how can I reduce (override) the width/size of text to keep the equation in just 2 lines rather than 4 lines. Thx

Comment: http://sis.smu.edu.sg/sites/default/files/sis/conference/aamas2016/paper-submission/aamas2016_example.zip

Comment: @NguyenDoanTung - Even with the "tricks" used in the answer above, I cannot get the equation to fit on just two lines when using the `aamas2016` document class and a `cases` environment, *unless* I also reduce the font size by 10 or 20 percent. I think that reducing the font size is a bad idea, typographically speaking -- much better to use four lines, really.